# Два раза jQuery(document).ready(function(){}); в скрипте не работает

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет всем! Вот такая проблема с javascript-ом у меня есть файл где есть

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){});
```

и есть основной файл то есть php файл javascript мне там нужен из за того что я вставляю в часть javascript php код. и оба скрипта имеют `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` и один из них не работает та которая после. Не знаю как решит люди помогите

Comment: У вас так и написано:

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){});

Или там всё-таки есть и тело функции? Тогда выложите весь код.
Может во второй функции есть ошибка.

Comment: что это за бред???

Comment: Там ошибка. `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})` устанавливает обработчик `ready`, в котором он еще раз устанавливается `jQuery(function(){})`.

Comment: так и что мне делать?

Comment: @KiTE прав, получается рекурсия и браузер блокирует её исполнение (по-идее)

Comment: @Crasher, ну вообще не рекурсия и вторая функция просто должна была выполниться сразу

Comment: @KiTE, это не ошибка, jQuery позволяет навешивать столько обработчиков на `ready` сколько нужно и все отрабатывает: http://jsfiddle.net/7x5mpodf/

Comment: :-D Да блин, как я на такие старые вопросы попадаю-то!

Answer (score 1):

Лучше через PHP генерить начинку для контейнера типа:

```
<script id="php_data" type="text/x-php-data">
</script>
```

А через JQuery ее читать и парсить. Например:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var data = jQuery('#php_data').html();
});
```

Comment: это быдло код было бы репутации сделал бы минус

Comment: Да?!! @FreelancerUz, а, я считаю, что быдлокод - это когда в JavaScript лепят PHP-шные вставки, и, тем самым, блокируют себе возможность вынести JavaScript-логику страницы в отдельный статичный файл. Или все-же выносят все отдельно, а потом создают в HTML еще один ready-обработчик...

Кстати, оказывается что быдлокодеры работают в Microsoft. Именно там разработали плагин [jQuery Templates][1], в котором предлагается отделять логику от переменного контента. А переменный контент хранить в контейнерах `<script>` с неизвестным для браузера `type`.

  [1]: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Comment: FreelancerUz, судя по структуре, Ваш быдлокод быдлокодее кода @KITE в 9 000 раз ;)

Answer (score 1):

> В теле второго скрипта(не рабочего):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // Слайдер Фотографии
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".photos").jCarouselLite({
        btnPrev: ".photo-next",
        btnNext: ".photo-prev",
        visible: <?=$photos_count?>,
        auto: 5000,
        speed: 700,
        vertical: true,
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Так. Разберемся с кодом. `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})` устанавливает функцию для выполнения после загрузки DOM. `jQuery(function(){})` выполняет то же самое. Так как событие загрузки DOM уже произошло, вешать на него функцию уже поздно. Поэтому уберите второй "навешиватель" и выполняйте функцию сразу.